# iOS calendar crashed on March 2013

Tags: ipad, ios, calendar

When selecting March 2013 in the Month view, Calendar crashes. Does anyone know what could be the cause of this ?

Ps: I tried march 2012 and the weekly view for march 2013 and there is no problem. 
Ps2: it's on a iPad 3 with iOS 6.0.1 
Ps3: I've tried the same thing on my father's iPad : It's crashes also on march 2013. (the synchronized calendar are totaly different)  
Ps4: Just found out that Facebook's birthdays are crashing the app on my iPad.

Comment: Maybe their is some weird entry in a calendar for that month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen if you have an all-day event on 1-Apr-2013. If you remove this event it won't crash.

Comment: I've seen a few reports that updating to iOS 6.1 fixes this, but I wasn't able to reproduce this either before or after the update.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to report that the update to iOS 6.1 solves this problem. I had the issue and now it's gone.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that having an event that merely *starts* between 0:00 and 0:59 on 2013-04-01 causes Calendar to crash when viewing March in month view. All-day events start at midnight, so this affects them too.

Moreover, if I create an event that starts on 2013-03-31 23:55 and ends at 2013-04-01 0:55, Calendar shows the event would magically go back in time and *end* on 2013-02-25:

[image: a bug march]

I'd suggest to [file a bug report](https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/) on the issue

Answer (score 0):

Jus tried this on my iPad 3 with iOS 6.0.1, no issue.

What calendars are syncing/subscribed to? Try temporarily disabling your accounts in *Mail, Contacts, Calendars* to see if that’s what affect it.